# When i call the controller method in which i write this code to send email. My webpage does not load . and it does not show any error

Tags: php, email, codeigniter-2

When i call the controller method in which i write this code

```
 $config = array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'me.atiq32@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '********'
    );
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->from('me.atiq32@gmail.com', 'Atiq');
    $this->email->to('***@yahoo.com');
    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

    if ($this->email->send()) {
        echo 'Email will be Sent';
    } else {
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
} '
```

to send email.
 My webpage does not load (in loading ....).
and even does not show any error.

Comment: Which line causes the page to not load?

Comment: @EricLeschinski He said no errors.

Comment: He also says the page does not load.  I can see his problem plain as day, I'm trying to teach a starving man to fish (by teaching him to debug), not give him a fish.  One problem is these no-experience developers are using stackoverflow as a replacement for basic debugging skills.  And these people need to be discouraged from filling stackoverflow with millions of damaging artefacts like this one, for others to land on and find useless.

Comment: When i comment this  `$this->email->send()` it works fine but when i un comment this. The page does not show any thing not before this and not after this. plz help me

Comment: `$this->email->send()` causes the page to not load !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are those stray characters at the very end? if yes they might be messing it up.

otherwise -- its hard to tell because we can't see all the code. what i do in situations like this is echo out a check before the method is called like

```
 echo " before email " ; 
 $this->sendemail() ; 
 echo " after email " ;
```

that gives you a sanity check to see where in the chain its breaking down. otherwise if you can't figure it out post more of your code.